# Chess Game with C ,alignment issue

Tags: c, chess, text-alignment

First of all, i don't know if the word alignment is the correct one to describe what i want help for so that's why i provide images from the console application.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

I want to know if there is a way to make the zeros be in order . I am providing to you my code .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int emptynes(int table1[16],int table2[16],int zero[32])
{
    int i,k=1;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        table1[i]=k;
        k++;
    }
    k=17;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        table2[i]=k;
        k++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
        zero[i]=0;
    return table1,table2,zero;
}
int firstloop(int table1[16])
{
    int i;
     for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        if(i==8)
        printf("\n\n");

        printf("%d   ",table1[i]);
        if(i<9)
            printf("   ");
        else
            printf("  ");
    }

}
int zeroloop(int zero[16])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        if(i%8==0)
            printf("\n\n");

        printf("%d      ",zero[i]);
    }
}
int secondloop(int table2[16])
{

    int i;
     for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        if(i==8)
        printf("\n\n");

        printf("%d     ",table2[i]);
        if(i<9)
            printf("");
    }
}
int twomoves(int x,int table1[16],int zero[32])
{
    int i,p=0,l=0;
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        if(x==table1[i])
          {
             p=i;
             break;
          }

    }
    if(i>8)
      l=table1[i]-8;
    if(zero[l]==0&&zero[l+8]==0)
    {
        zero[l+7]=table1[i];
        table1[i]=0;
    }
    return zero,table1;
}

int main()
        {
            printf("\n\n\n");
            int table1[16],table2[16],zero[32];
            int i,x,y,p;
            emptynes(table1,table2,zero);
            firstloop(table1);
            zeroloop(zero);
            printf("\n\n");
            secondloop(table2);
            printf("\n\n\n");
            printf("Player 1: Pawn & Moves -> ");
            scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
            twomoves(x,table1,zero); // do it as loop
            firstloop(table1);
            zeroloop(zero);
            printf("\n\n");
            secondloop(table2);

            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: please indent your code! And show us what you mean by "in order", maybe add an example.

Comment: Try "%10d" format string

Comment: ah now I see what you mean. This whole time, I was thinking about data structure alignement. Jonathon's solution should work.

Comment: `return zero,table1;` never saw that before , you can return diffenrents value in C ?

Comment: @Gabson: No, he can't. This `return zero,table1;` is equivalent to `return table1;`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a width specifier:

```
// Use (at least) 2 chars. 
printf("%2d  ", table1[i]);  

// Use (at least) 2 chars. The minus means left adjustment.
printf("%-2d  ", table1[i]);  

// Use (at least) 2 chars, zero-padded. 
printf("%02d  ", table1[i]);
```

Output:

```
 7
7
07
```